# Blank page after redirect customer to custom thank you page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have this custom code in my plugin for WordPress. The code will redirect the user to the custom thank you page I've created using elementor. I'm facing a problem with the template I've created, I'm unable to see the order recap. I'm only able to see a back button I've added but not the widget. How I can fix the code or customize using elementor the after order checkout page?

```php
    #
    public function redirect_customer_after_order( $order_id )
    {
        if( is_checkout() && isset( $wp->query_vars['order-received'] ) ){
            wp_safe_redirect( site_url( 'riepilogo-ordine' ) );
            exit;
        }
    }
    add_action('woocommerce_thankyou', array($this, 'redirect_customer_after_order'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you forget to declare `global $wp;`

Try below code

```
public function redirect_customer_after_order( $order_id )
{
    global $wp;
    if( is_checkout() && isset( $wp->query_vars['order-received'] ) ){
        wp_safe_redirect( site_url( 'riepilogo-ordine' ) );
        exit;
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_thankyou', array($this, 'redirect_customer_after_order'));
```

Alternatively you can use this code using the `is_wc_endpoint_url()` wc function

```
public function redirect_customer_after_order( $order_id )
{
    if( is_wc_endpoint_url( 'order-received' ) ){
        wp_safe_redirect( site_url( 'riepilogo-ordine' ) );
        exit;
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_thankyou', array($this, 'redirect_customer_after_order'));
```

Comment: it's not a problem with the `$wp` global, I've added it and I still see a blank page. What I need is to have the order recap page, as I said, it will be not loaded